# How to get last updated row or ID in wordpress

Tags: functions, mysql

How to get last updated row or ID in wordpress.

Like :  `$wpdb->insert_id;`

Comment: you have to use it after $wpdb->insert() is executed. Have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1576018/how-to-get-last-inserted-row-id-from-wordpress-database

Comment: I get last insert id.. but how I get last updated id...

Comment: In codeigniter `$this->db->affected_rows` that type in wordpress get the last affected_rows. It passable?.

Comment: i don't think there's a default function for it, what are you trying to update?

Comment: ok.. I get the last affected id and insert in the another table.. that only I ask last affected id getting is passable?.

Comment: By passable, you mean in a function or in your custom query?

Comment: yeah, the best way would be to create a custom query as per the use case.

Comment: Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20310298/get-the-id-of-the-last-updated-record).

Comment: Not sure about CodeIgnitier, but `affected_rows` refers to a _count_ of rows in mysqli API, not _specific_ rows. This doesn't seem easily possible on MySQL level, unless I am missing it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

> There is no equivalent function. `$wpdb->insert_id` works only after `$wpdb->insert`

**Alternative way**

If it's an update, you can either get the id with a query based on the data you have got, or most of the time, you should have already got the id before update it.

```
global $wpdb;

$data = array(
    'first_name' => "John",
    'last_name' => "Doe"
);

$where = array(
    'id' => $my_id
);

$res_update = $wpdb->update( $wpdb->prefix . "my_table", $data, $where );

if( $res_update === false ){
     error_log( 'my error');
}

return $my_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Once again select the same row updated on success.

```
 if($wpdb->last_error !== '') {
      //throw error stuffs
    }else{
     $last_updated_row = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->prefix . 'my_table' WHERE id = $my_id");  

    }
```